# pass inline arguments to shell script saved in in hdfs

Tags: bash, shell, unix, hadoop

I have a shell script on hdfs that accepts 8-9 parameters.
Normally, I can carry it out as follows:

```
sh sample.sh -mode FULL -status DELETE -id 1456 -region AP -path </path/to/filepath>
```

I tried `hadoop fs -cat /dev/test/sample.sh | exec bash -mode FULL -status DELETE -id 1456 -region AP -path /dev/resultsFolder`
Even though I pass these arguments they are not read and script executes without the arguments.
Threw error as  `No such file or directory` What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Please write your code **exactly** as you use it. You will for sure not write `-cat <..>`, i.e. using angle brackets. Also, explain what you mean by _These may not work_. Either it works, or it doesn't. You need to know, and if it doesn't work, you need to describe in what respect it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
bash -c "$(hadoop fs -cat /dev/test/sample.sh)" bash -mode FULL -status DELETE -id 1456 -region AP -path /dev/resultsFolder
```

would work also.

> `-c`  If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument *command_string*.  If  there  are  arguments  after  the  *command_string*, the first argument is assigned to `$0` and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.  The assignment to `$0` sets
> the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

Perhaps more readably (although `bash -s` is rather elegant)

```sh
code=$(hadoop fs -cat /dev/test/sample.sh)
bash -c "$code" bash -mode FULL -status DELETE -id 1456 -region AP -path /dev/resultsFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

`bash -mode FULL` passes the `-mode` and `FULL` parameter to bash, not to your script.  From the bash man page, describing the options:

> `--        A` -- signals the end of options and disables further option processing.  Any  arguments after the -- are treated as filenames and arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.

and:

> `-s`        If  the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after option processing, then commands are read from the standard input.  This option allows  the positional parameters to be set when invoking an interactive shell.

I would therefore invoke it as

```
.... | bash - --mode FULL ....
```

According to the comment given by Gordon Davisson, we need to use `-s` here:

```
.... | bash -s -- -mode FULL ....
```

Comment: bash will still treat the first argument after `--` as a filename to run as the command. You want `bash -s -- --mode FULL ...`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: I thought about -s first, but since according to the man-page, a lone `-` implies `--`, and `--` signals the end of the options, I found `-`  simpler and more logical. Is the man-page incorrect in this description? Otherwise, which point did I misunderstand?

Comment: `--` signals the end of bash options, but "Any arguments after the `--` are treated as **filenames** and arguments", and the first one after `--` is taken as the name of the script. Try it: if you run `bash - -mode FULL`, you will get a "bash: -mode: No such file or directory" error because it's trying to run a script file named `-mode`. So you need both `-s` to run commands from stdin instead of a named file, and `--` so that `-mode` isn't treated as bash options.

Comment: Ah, got it. But then, what is the purpose of a lone `-`? It is supposed to represent stdin as input file, isn't it?

Comment: In some situations, but apparently not this one. I get "bash: -: No such file or directory". I'd recommend testing your code to make sure it actually works.

Comment: the above options doesnt work with hadooop, but in unix i am able to run